# Auto populate column 2 which is also drop down based value based on user selection in column 1 drop down

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Can any one let me know how can i auto populate column 2 which is also a drop down based value and this column is person who needs to work on the ticket when user selects a value in column 1. 
So that based on this i need to send an email to the person which is assigned.
For example
Column 1
If user selects Networks and Field services then
 - Column 2 should be "Padmini"
I am not sure how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We could use SharePoint designer 2013 platform workflow to meet your requirement.

Use "If any value equals any value" action and "Set field in Current item" action as shown below:

[image]

Start options:

[image]

And Drop1 and Drop2 column are all drop down columns.

Comment: Hello Julie , Thank you so much for a simple workaround , but i have more if conditions like around 10-12 is it possible to give one by one 10 conditions?

Comment: Yes you could do this.